# Reading SWF Header with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to read the header of an SWF file using NSData.
According to SWF format specification I need to access movie's width and height reading bits, not bytes, and I couldn't find a way to do it in Obj-C

> > Bytes 9 thru ?: Here is stored a RECT (bounds of movie). It must be read in binary form. First of all, we will transform the first byte to binary: "01100000"
> >         The first 5 bits will tell us the size in bits of each stored value: "01100" = 12
> >         So, we have 4 fields of 12 bits = 48 bits
> >         48 bits + 5 bits (header of RECT) = 53 bits
> >         Fill to complete bytes with zeroes, till we reach a multiple of 8. 53 bits + 3 alignment bits = 56 bits (this RECT is 7 bytes length, 7 * 8 = 56)
> >         I use this formula to determine all this stuff:

Where do I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by looking for code with a compatible license that already does what you want. C libraries can be used from Obj-C code simply by linking them in (or arranging for them to be dynamically linked in) and then calling their functions.

Failing that, start by looking at the [Binary Data Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/BinaryData.html) and [NSData Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You'd want to pull out the bytes that contain the bits you're interested in, then use bit masking techniques to extract the bits you care about. You might find the `BitTst()`, `BitSet()`, and `BitClr()` functions and their friends useful, if they're still there in Snow Leopard; I'm not sure whether they ended up in the démodé parts of Carbon or not. There are also the Posix `setbit()`, `clrbit()`, `isset()`, and `isclr()` macros defined in . Then, finally, there are the C bitwise operators: `^`, `|`, `&`, `~`, `<<`, and `>>`.

Comment: Just a note that it is not possible to dynamically link to libraries, if this is for an iPhone application.

Answer (score 2):

ObjC is a superset of C: You can run C code alongside ObjC with no issues.

Thus, you could use a C-based library like [libming](http://www.libming.org/WhatsIncluded) to read bytes from your SWF file.

If you need to shuffle bytes into an `NSData` object, look into the `-dataWithBytes:length:` method.

Comment: I just found another C program to read the SWF header, it seems to work fine and I can compile it with no issues. Now I'm trying to figure out how to mix the pure C with my Obj-C application.